# Can the fractal dimension of a coastline be less than 1?

Tags: calculus, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, fractal-analysis

I am currently investigating the fractal dimension of the coastline of the island the Palm Jumeirah, including the crescent. Using the Hausdorff method I have reached an answer of 0.879. This is less than 1 and i thought the range of the value was between 1 and 2 (closer to 2 = more complex coastline). Can someone please tell me what this means or whether I have probably made an error?

[method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm2kX.jpg)

[graph and calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxd0R.png)

Comment: Yes, you've made an error somewhere. The Hausdorff dimension can't be less than 1, since that's the measure for a normal line segment.

Comment: Yes, please show your work so we can positively identify the error.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done?  What do you mean by the "Hausdorff method"?

Comment: I'll paste my working below, from what i understand as the length of the ruler decreases, the length of the measured coastline should increase. I found with this one that the length of the ruler and coastline increases in direct proportion rather than inversely:

Comment: i've added the images in the original post/comment

Answer (score 1):

The algebra is correct, but the data is wrong.

In your diagrams, the rulers - especially the long ones - stick out past the edge of the Palm Jumeriah into the sea. The overestimation of L for large G is stronger than any fractal properties the coastline has, which means that L decreases with G. To get a more accurate dimension, make sure that every ruler starts and ends on the coastline.

Being man-made, the coastline itself is very smooth so probably has an actual Hausdorff dimension close to (but greater than) 1.